# Azure File share SAS token signature not generating as expected, How do one generate signature for file object to match the one generated in portal?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, signature

I am trying to create a signature for SAS token programmatically which should match with the one generated in the azure portal when a user selects few options. However the documentation is so confusing and doesn't guide you to achieve what is needed for the action. I have a file in azure file share and I want to access it by generating SAS token and sign it. I can easily do it by selecting the appropriate options in Azure portal and access the file, but I want to do the exact thing programmatically. I tried by java but the resulted SAS token signature doesn't match. Please help me.

Below is the SAS token when I generate it through Azure Portal:

```
?sv=2019-12-12&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-11-23T12:20:39Z&st=2020-11-23T04:20:39Z&spr=https&sig=XI%2FlSZSXp54XVwk2G%2F23j%2FjqsrojVqJoAonh6gdaAPk%3D
```

The corresponding options selected in azure portal for above sas token is as follows as shown in below image
[image]

The key used is **key1** and is as follows:

```
l1wxekiJj9IcTw350w5c1MtVfYVP3qcz3zdxzCCp+YVaXqs9faOJfl/Z07AoLDnsnyn+POGjxjcFy3EF9g/r9Q==
```

What I tried is to generate a signature for the below options(String to Sign) as taken from the generated SAS token by azure portal and using the key1 above.

```
sv=2019-12-12&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-11-23T12:20:39Z&st=2020-11-23T04:20:39Z&spr=https
```

Below is my java code which generates the signature for the above string to sign

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
public class GenerateSAS {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Mac sha256_HMAC = null;
        String hash = null;
        String input="sv=2019-12-12&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-11-23T12:20:39Z&st=2020-11-23T04:20:39Z&spr=https";
        input=URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");
        String key="l1wxekiJj9IcTw350w5c1MtVfYVP3qcz3zdxzCCp+YVaXqs9faOJfl/Z07AoLDnsnyn+POGjxjcFy3EF9g/r9Q==";
        sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        hash = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        System.out.println(hash);
    }
```

The above code generates signature which is `MK/uu+NlURscoX1dymzipRN/Jb4aXyVzfbIVBz8l02M=` and this is not equal to what was generated in the azure portal, which was `XI%2FlSZSXp54XVwk2G%2F23j%2FjqsrojVqJoAonh6gdaAPk%3D`

Please help me to generate the signature correctly which shall help me append it to SAS token for file object access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create sas token to access Azure file service resource, the signature string should be like as below. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas)

```
StringToSign = accountname + "\n" +  
    signedpermissions + "\n" +  
    signedservice + "\n" +  
    signedresourcetype + "\n" +  
    signedstart + "\n" +  
    signedexpiry + "\n" +  
    signedIP + "\n" +  
    signedProtocol + "\n" +  
    signedversion + "\n"
```

For example

```
 public static void createSasToken(){

    String accountName = "accountName";
    String key = "accountKey";
    String resourceUrl = "https://"+accountName+".file.core.windows.net/fileShare/fileName";
    /**
     * please note the date formate should be  ISO 8601 UTC formats 
     * for further information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/formatting-datetime-values
    */
    String start = "startTime";
    String expiry = "expiry";
    String apiVersion = "2019-12-12";

    String stringToSign = accountName + "\n" +
                "r\n" +
                "f\n" +
                "o\n" +
                start + "\n" +
                expiry + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "https\n" +
                apiVersion +"\n";

    String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);

    try{

        String sasToken = "sv=" + azureApiVersion +
            "&ss=f" +
            "&srt=o" +
            "&sp=r" +
            "&se=" +URLEncoder.encode(expiry, "UTF-8") +
            "&st=" + URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") +
            "&spr=https" +
            "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(resourceUrl+"?"+sasToken);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getHMAC256(String accountKey, String signStr) {
    String signature = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256");
        Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
        signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(signStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signature;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jim, I am very thankful to you. I was referring to "create a service sas", but the correct documentation was "create an account sas". Thank you very much for helping me out.